# Can't properly write a tiff file

Tags: c, gcc, graphics, x86-64, tiff

I have a program which has the following function to write to a tiff file. However, the files produced are not recognized by any picture viewing software. What is wrong in this code, why is it not producing proper tiff files? Note that it uses the `libtiff` library.

```
long WriteGrayscaleTIFF(char *filename, long width, 
        long height, long scanbytes, unsigned char *data)
{
    long y;
    double factor;
    long c;
    unsigned long cmap[256];           /* output color map */
    TIFF *outimage;                     /* TIFF image handle */

    /* create a grayscale ramp for the output color map */
    factor = (double)((1 << 16) - 1) / (double)((1 << 8) - 1);
    for (c = 0; c < 256; c++)
        cmap[c] = (long)(c * factor);

    /* open and initialize output file */
    if ((outimage = TIFFOpen(filename, "w")) == NULL)
        return(0);
    TIFFSetField(outimage, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width);
    TIFFSetField(outimage, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height);
    TIFFSetField(outimage, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 8);
    TIFFSetField(outimage, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
    TIFFSetField(outimage, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
    TIFFSetField(outimage, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, COMPRESSION_LZW);
    TIFFSetField(outimage, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_BOTLEFT);
    TIFFSetField(outimage, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_PALETTE);
    TIFFSetField(outimage, TIFFTAG_COLORMAP, cmap, cmap, cmap);

    /* write the image data */
    printf( "height = %d, width = %d!\n", height, width );
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        if (!TIFFWriteScanline(outimage, data, y, 0)) 
        {
            printf( "TIFFClose!\n" );
            TIFFClose(outimage);
            return(0);
        }
        data += scanbytes;
    }

    /* close the file */
    TIFFClose(outimage);
    return(1);
}
```

Comment: I just tested this and it works, are you still having trouble with this?